# Android : Jackson with ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, json, gson, jackson, activeandroid

ActiveAndroid has a constraint that all its entities need to inherit from a certain base class and need to have a one parameter constructor taking in the Context (from the activity) as the input. [Not a fan to this constraint].

With gson, I can create a type adapter to get around this constraint.

```
public class PolicyInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Policy>{
    private Context context;

    public PolicyInstanceCreator(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Policy createInstance(Type type) {
        return new Policy(context);
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Policy.class, new PolicyInstanceCreator(context)).create();
Policy[] policies = gson.fromJson(myString, Policy[].class);
```

One possibility seems to be that we need to implement a custom desearlizer with Jackson.

Are there any alternatives to having to write a custom deserializer for jackson or is that my only option with a specific one parameter constructor?

Please let me know if there are any alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to apply mix-in annotations (see this [wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), or [this blog post](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html)) to add @JsonCreator to specify that this specific constructor is to be used.
This requires either that 'Context' comes from JSON (name in JSON can be specified with @JsonProperty on constructor parameter); or that it is ok to pass in null (which occurs if no such field is found from JSON).
If an actual external context object needs to be passed, custom deserializer is the way to go (until 'external value injection' is implemented; this is planned but not yet added).

Comment: The context is the Activity itself. I am not familiar with java much, but looking at the post I am not sure if what Active Android wants can be done. I really don'y like ActiveAndroi's imposed inheritance that is the root of this issue. Might have to switch out the ORM. gson is way slower compared to jackson, hence the choice, else gson has an elegant solution to handle instantiation.

Comment: Yeah, design of the class certainly is wrong in an old-fashioned kinda wrong way. :-) ... as to instantiation, perhaps Jackson does need a way to register instantiators; that should be trivial to add, if it's commonly needed.

Comment: That would be great. Are you involved with the project?

Comment: Yes, I am a Jackson developer (cowtowncoder on mailing lists)

Comment: Well, what are your thoughts, could you add this soon enough? That would make the entity's json to database conversion less painful and we get to keep using jackson. InstanceCreator would a great feature when dealing with things like ActiveAndroid that impose inheritance.

Comment: How about we take this to the mailing list? I did add a Jira wish for it, but can't promise it'll be done on very short term (i.e. if you need it now, need to use a work0around). It is a good feature, so good chance to get in 1.9, but with open source things are pretty fluid... :)

Comment: what would be a proposed workaround? I do not think the mixin method would work with the context from the activity.

Comment: Unfortunately it'd be custom deserializer. I guess "workaround" would imply something simpler, but I don't there is anything.

Comment: have you used any other orm on android with good effect? May be I need to switch from active android due to this imposed inheritance business.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't done much android development, just helped others with simple admin apps, client-side for accessing REST services... wish I knew better choices, but just haven't done ORM there. On regular J2SE I use jDBI, but I don't know what kind of limitations Android platform might put for jdbc-based libs.